# Jquery: animate invalid

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
  elem.animate({ background-image: "url(" + imagedir + backgrounds[i] + ")" }, 1500 );
                    });
```

But apparently this is invalid, can anyone see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling us what program is giving what errors (is it the browser console? A validator?), but I'm pretty sure it won't work (if that's what you mean by invalid) due to the fact you can't animate `background-image`.

DreamWeaver will be moaning at you probably because `background-image` isn't a JavaScript CSS attribute. Use `backgroundImage` or, specifically to jQuery, wrap it in quotes: `"background-image"`. To simply change the background image, use `.css()` instead of `.animate()`, but this won't fade it. Is the image a single colour or an actual image?

---

If you want to fade between two images, there is a solution using two separate images, one inside a container. There's a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/Rq84s/) demonstrating this.

#### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div
{
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    background: url('http://www.traveltovietnam.cc/Upload/Tour/2352008111155_SplendorOfMuiNeBeachMuiNe2.jpg');
}

div div
{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: url('http://www.travelwizard.com/caribbean/media/sandy%20lane%20beach.jpg');
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".outer").hover(function() {
        $(this).children().fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: its dreamweaver, showing a red square on that line of code meaning its incorrect syntax

Answer (score 3):

> 1) You can't animate a background (background position maybe but not the background image itself)
>   2) the proper css name would be backgroundImage and not background-image

Comment: +1 Trying to animate the background leads all sorts of errors in <IE9

Comment: @fewpeople Good to know.  I wouldn't even try it, myself. :P

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect to animate it? For animation needs to change some **numeric** value (width, opacity, etc.) but in your case - no number values.

You can't use animation with `background-image` property. At least in such way.